# Laravel and Google Cloud: is not ready and cannot serve traffic

Tags: laravel, docker, google-cloud-platform

I keep getting this error on GCP:

> Step #2 - "Deploy": ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.update) Revision
> '########-00014-kit' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The
> user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined
> provided by the PORT=80 environment variable. Logs for this revision
> might contain more information.

This is my current dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.2

COPY ./gcloud-custom-configs/apache/ /etc/apache2/sites-available/
COPY ./ /var/www/html/

# ADD ./ /var/www/html/
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# ADD ./gcloud-custom-configs/apache/ /etc/apache2/sites-available/

# COPY .env.example .env

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y git zip unzip && \
    curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer && \
    composer install --no-dev --no-interaction --optimize-autoloader && \
    composer require google/cloud-logging google/cloud-error-reporting --with-all-dependencies && \
    chmod 0777 -R storage/ && \
    chmod 0777 -R bootstrap/cache/

# Expose port 80 (if necessary)
# EXPOSE 80

# Start the Apache server
# CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

Is there anything missing?

Comment: Which version of Google cloud CLI are you using? This issue might be fixed with the version less than `430.0.0` as stated in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#cloud_run_3)

Comment: Does Laravel work correctly when you run the container locally in Docker? Review the Cloud Run logs for error messages.

Answer (score 1):

This issue might be fixed with the version less than `430.0.0` as stated in the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#cloud_run_3). Make sure your Google cloud CLI version is less than `430.0.0`.

Also as @John Hanley suggested in the comments, Make sure Laravel works correctly when you run the container locally in Docker. Also Review the Cloud Run logs for error messages to find the cause of the error.

Also check with this [Troubleshooting Document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start), which states the potential causes of the error:

> 1. Verify that you can [run your container image locally](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local). If your container image cannot    run locally, you need to diagnose and fix the issue locally first.
> 2. Check if your container is listening for requests on the expected port as documented in the [container runtime contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#port). Your container must listen for incoming requests on the port that is defined by Cloud Run and provided in the PORT environment variable. See [Configuring containers](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/containers) for instructions on how to specify the port.
> 3. Check if your container is listening on all network interfaces, commonly denoted as 0.0.0.0.
> 4. Verify that your container image is compiled for 64-bit Linux as required by the [container runtime contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract#languages).
>    `Note: If you build your container image on a ARM based machine, then it might not work as expected when used with Cloud Run. To solve this issue, build your image using Cloud Build.`
> 5. Use Cloud Logging to [look for application errors in stdout or stderr logs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/logging). You can also [look for crashes captured in Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/error-reporting).
>    You might need to update your code or your revision settings to fix errors or crashes. You can also [troubleshoot your service locally](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/local-troubleshooting).